# How to send HTTP post request from a sample C Program

Tags: c++, rest, mfc

I want to make HTTP post/get request from my CPP code to a server.
I have limitation of using MFC libraries only as my project has to be compiled using MFC.

Comment: Have you looked at WinHttp and/or libcurl?

Comment: You can also use [WinInet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/about-wininet), it's easier than WinHttp

Comment: @SVM I don't think your question is too broad. The default way for doing http in MFC is using the classes `CInternetSession`and `CHttpConnection` (if you don't want to use the IE ActiveX wrapper).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `libcurl` as mentionned previously, have a look at this tutorial explaining how to create HTTP requests : [HTTP Requests with curl](https://ec.haxx.se/libcurl-http-requests.html)

You can also find [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) some examples of code using this library.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not use any extra libraries like `libcurl` (it is very powerful cross-platform network library), your only option is WinInet and its MFC wrapper. You can find documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/writing-an-internet-client-application-using-mfc-wininet-classes?view=vs-2019

And all classes reference here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/win32-internet-classes?view=vs-2019

Comment: I think this qualifies as a link only answer

Comment: You prefer I copy and paste WinInet documentation here? The question is about library selection, I pointed to this library.